# Exclude acf properties from posts schema WP REST API

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-rest-api

I use plugins: ACF and ACF to REST API.
I created group of custom fields, turned on it to show and edit in rest. And setup it to show only post type - post. Ok. I got acf object with my custom fields in rest api as `/wp-json/wp/post/1` and `/wp-json/acf/v3/posts/1`.

But I want to get these properties in **only** url `/wp-json/acf/v3/posts/1`, not `/wp-json/wp/post/1`. In other words, these properties mustn't be in Post Api object.

How can I do it properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using my plugin.

Please copy and paste the [filter](https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api#filters) below in your **functions.php**.

```
add_filter( 'acf/rest_api/post/get_fields', function( $item, $request ) {
    if ( is_array( $request ) ) {
        $item = array();
    }

    return $item;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Thanks